# Circuit wires not printing out while downloading the PDF file

Tags: circuitikz, printing

Basically, I have this code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{circuitikz} [american voltages, american currents]
        \draw 
            (0,0) to (0, 0)
            to [ V = $V_g$, invert] (0, 2);
        \draw
            to (0, 2)
            to [ R, l_ = $R_1$ ] (2, 2);
        \path
            to (2, 2)
            to (0, 2);    
        \draw[dashed]
            to (0, 2)
            to (0, 4);
        \draw
            (0, 4)
            to [ voltmeter ] (2, 4);
        \draw[dashed]
            to (2, 4)
            to (2, 2);
        \path
            (2, 4);
        \draw
            (2, 4)
            to [ voltmeter ] (4, 4);
        \draw[dashed]
            to (4, 4)
            to (4, 2);
        \draw
            (4, 4)
            to [ voltmeter ] (6, 4);
        \draw[dashed]
            to (6, 4)
            to (6, 2);
        \path
            to (0, 4);
        \draw[dashed]
            to (0, 4)
            to (0, 6);
        \draw
            to (0, 6)
            to [ voltmeter ] (6, 6);
        \draw[dashed]
            to (6, 6)
            to (6, 4);
        \draw
            to (2, 2)
            to [ R, l_ = $R_2$ ] (4, 2)
            to [ R, l_ = $R_3$ ] (6, 2)
            to (6, 0);
        \path
            to (0, 0);
        \draw
            to (0, 0)
            to [ ammeter ] (6, 0);
        \end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
```

Which *should* print out like this (which does on the PDF viewer).
[image: Preview seen inside the editor.]

But instead, it prints out like this on the PDF file:

[image: Actual printout in the PDF file.]

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  What kind of printer are you using, and what is its resolution?

Comment: Hello, thank you. I'm using Overleaf, not really sure what printer it uses.

Comment: Overleaf is (remote) editor and it doesn't use any printer but compile your code to `.pdf` file, which you can see in Overleaf preview window. If there  are missed some lines, than they are not defined in your code. BTW, your code is a bit strange and if I inserted it in some my working document doesn't produce first image in your question. You should fix your code first.

Comment: You should be aware that command `\path` doesn't draw visible lines.

Comment: @Zarko this is strange code, yes - maybe machine-produced? But the main problem is the (wrong) `\draw to ...` idiom, which generates code that seems to be interpreted differently by different PDF processors.

Comment: @Rmano, you are right. I try to redraw OP sheme, but I didn't figured draw how to draw correctly ammeter between coordinates `(6,0)` and `(0,0)`. +1 for your nice answer.

Comment: Note that it is possible to do an entire circuit with one \draw.  (Two if you also  use dashed lines.)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to simplify the problem. If I compile this small part (I added the red dot to have a reference to `(0,0)`):

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} [american voltages, american currents]
        \draw
        (0,0) to (0,0) node[circ,red]{}
            to [ V = $V_g$, invert] (0, 2);
        \draw
            to (0, 2)
            to [ R, l_ = $R_1$ ] (2, 2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

you have the following:

[image]

See the gap? This is because your second draw uses `\draw to (0,2)` and `to` **needs** a starting coordinate explicitly. The first `(0,0) to (0,0)` also is doing nothing...

If you change the code to

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} [american voltages, american currents]
    \draw
    (0,0) node[circ,red]{}
    to [ V = $V_g$, invert] (0, 2);
    \draw
    (0, 2)
    to [ R, l_ = $R_1$ ] (2, 2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

You have the correct one:

[image]

The current point is not "reminded" from one draw to another one, in other words. BTW, the code is much easier to write (I removed the red dot) as:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} [american voltages, american currents]
    \draw
    (0,0)
    to [ V = $V_g$, invert] (0, 2)
    to [ R, l_ = $R_1$ ] (2, 2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Also, the `\path` elements are basically doing nothing here.

What is strange is that you have a previsualization with the lines... I have consistent white gaps in both preview and printing.

A possible code for your drawing (but you should try to reduce the number of different paths) could be:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} [american voltages, american currents]
    \draw (0,0)
    to [ V = $V_g$, invert] (0, 2)
    to [ R, l_ = $R_1$ ] (2, 2);
    \draw[dashed] (0, 2) -- (0, 4);
    \draw (0, 4) to [ voltmeter ] (2, 4);
    \draw[dashed] (2, 4) -- (2, 2);
    \draw (2, 4) to [ voltmeter ] (4, 4);
    \draw[dashed] (4, 4) to (4, 2);
    \draw (4, 4) to [ voltmeter ] (6, 4);
    \draw[dashed] (6, 4) -- (6, 2);
    \draw[dashed] (0, 4) -- (0, 6);
    \draw (0, 6) to [ voltmeter ] (6, 6);
    \draw[dashed] (6, 6) to (6, 4);
    \draw (2, 2) to [ R, l_ = $R_2$ ] (4, 2)
        to [ R, l_ = $R_3$ ] (6, 2)-- (6, 0);
    \draw (0, 0) to [ ammeter ] (6, 0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One more version how to correct draw your sheme in one loop and add dashed lines separate:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages, american currents]
\draw   (0,0)   to [V = $Vg$, invert]  (0,2)
                to [R = $R_1$ ] (2,2)
                to [R = $R_2$ ] (4,2)
                to [R = $R_3$ ] (6,2)
                to [short]      (6,0)
                to [ammeter, invert, mirror]    (0,0)
        (0,4)   to [voltmeter]  (2,4)
                to [voltmeter]  (4,4)
                to [voltmeter]  (6,4)
        (0,6)   to [voltmeter]  (6,6);
\draw[dash pattern=on 2mm off 1mm]
        (0,2) -- (0,6)
        (2,2) -- (2,4)
        (4,2) -- (4,4)
        (6,2) -- (6,6);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]